# Multiple Launch Files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to debug multiple files from a single folder?  I had expected that I could create multiple launch files in the .settings folder and pick the one I want to execute, but that did not seem to work.  It seems to insist on only 'launch.json'.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

VSCode supports only one launch.json, but you can have multiple launch configurations inside one launch.json. The example at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging has 3 different launch configurations. You can specify any amount, and choose the active one using a drop down in the debug view.

Comment: Some practical details: In the Run menu, select Open Configurations, and then Add Configuration. Edit the configuration as necessary. To select a configuration, select it on the status bar at the bottom of VSCode.

Answer (score 8):

**Visual studio code allows to launch multiple configurations at once.**

check out the **[Compound Launch Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations)** in Visual Studio Code Website

NOTE: switch the Java Debug console from Integrated Terminal to Integrated Console so that all launch configurations will be displayed & will work correct acoordinglt to your expectations

Comment: Since this question comes up first on google for "debugging multiple files at once," the detail of adding a "compounds" section is important.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is about multiple configurations for a single folder, just want to mention the alternative: multiple folders in a single workspace, each with their own *launch.json*.

One way is to just copy the `.vscode/launch.json` file to the other folder and edit it. The desired configuration can be picked up or edited from the drop-down to the right of the "Start Debugging" (Green "play") button.

Comment: "multiple folders in a single workspace, each with their own launch.json", i tried this, but when i debug, only the root launch.json is being used, any idea why?

Comment: I don't know why, I'd speculate that the higher folder has precedence. I can't remember how I did this, but probably there wasn't a "root launch.json". If you already have a `launch.json` for each folder, maybe you don't need one for the parent... looking at my configuration now, I still have two folders in the workspace, but only one has a `launch.json`, for the project where I actually use GDB. The other is just a related repository.

Comment: Remove the (second) folder with `launch.json` from the workspace and add it back as in Step 4 and 6 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290687/301049, then the entries appear in the list.

Answer (score 3):

use Multi-root workspaces
Multi-root workspaces are an advanced capability of VS Code that allows you to configure multiple distinct folders to be part of the workspace. Instead of opening a folder as workspace, you will open a .code-workspace JSON file that lists the folders of the workspace. For example:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "my-folder-a"
    },
    {
      "path": "my-folder-b"
    }
  ]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces

so you can use multiple launch.json

Answer (score 2):

Here are steps what I do to have 2 projects(A and B) and I can switch between them when I need to build or run

1. Create an empty Workspace
2. Add the `Project A` by choosing `Add Folder to Workspace`
3. Add tasks.json and launch.json to the project. Basically VS Code will help you to do that correctly. If there is something wrong, just delete `.vscode folder` and do again
4. Remove the folder of project A out of the Workspace
5. Do `step 2,3` for `Project B`
6. Add project A again to the Workspace. Now, we will have 2 project A and B in the Workspace with their own `.vscode`

   - When you press `Ctrl + Shift +  B`, VS Code will ask you which one you want to build
   - To debug or start without debug, you press `Ctrl + Shift + D` then on the left top selector, you select which project you want to run