# How Launch Multiple HTML files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to launch HTML multiple files in the same folder, and open them in Chrome (not a new window with every file) in Visual Studio Code. I tried this solution: [Multiple Launch Files in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277191/multiple-launch-files-in-visual-studio-code), but I think, I am missing something.

I always get the message to close my current debug session before starting a new one.

Here is my launch.json file for the folder:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Chrome1",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file":"${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chrome2",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Chrome3",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}"
        }
    ],
        "compounds": [
            {
              "name": "Chrome1/Chrome2/Chrome3",
              "configurations": ["Launch Chrome","Launch Chrome","Launch Chrome"],
              "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
            }
        ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using live server to launch files?

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with the live server. But I am interested in debugging multiple files.

Comment: there is no launch config named `Launch Chrome`, and all 3 configs use the same file

Comment: Even if I change my configurations to:  "compounds": [
            {
              "name": "Chrome1/Chrome2/Chrome3",
              "configurations": ["Chrome1","Chrome2","Chrome3"],
              "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
            }
        ]; Nothing good happens.

Comment: Also, correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't ${file} says current file. Hence, if I change current/active file, so should be the value of ${file}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does open chrome with 3 tab for 3 debug.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Chrome1",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/a.html"
        }, {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Chrome2",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/b.html"
        }, {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Chrome3",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/c.html"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [{
        "name": "Chrome123",
        "configurations": ["Chrome1", "Chrome2", "Chrome3"],
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked so far. But the only thing is when I separately launch Chrome1, Chrome2 and Chrome3, the output is as expected, but when I debug with Chrome123, only the first file executed (launches in the browser), while the rest are "about:blank".