# How to easily switch msys2 compilers in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

I am using the msys2 compiler with VSCode on Windows and would like to be able to easily switch between the MingW64, UCRT64 and Clang64 compilers.
The default setup according to the MSys2 website is to add the msys2 base bin directory as well as the bin directory of the respective environment to the path:

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin
```

This has several effects:
nice is that you can use the standard gnu tools from `C:\msys64\usr\bin` everywhere, like the `less` command.
What is not nice is that you have to change the path to change the compiler, but this is not passed to the running VSCode environment, which you therefore have to exit and restart first.
Now I can set environment variables in the launch.json files or the configurations of the internal terminals of VSCode.
However, it is very unhandy to add only a small entry to the Windows path.

Now I see the following:

- In the launch.json there are the entries
  `"MIMODE"`and `"miDebuggerPath"`
- In the environment variables of the msys environments there are the environment variables
  `MSYSTEM` and `MSYSTEM_Prefix` (and some others), which are not defined in the windows cmd prompt.
  Would possibly the definition of these variables in the launch configuration be enough for msys to find everything?
  Then I could just

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin
```

in the default path, which would give me access to standard msys2 tools, but control the compiler selection exclusively via the definitions in launch.json.
The only disadvantage would be not having immediate access to a predefined compiler in a "normal" terminal window - but this is also an advantage, because I can simply load the necessary environment variables there via batch file and can then just as easily select from the compiler environments.

In the documentation of VSCode it says
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment
that the configuration of the environment variables has to look like this:

```
[ { "name": "config", "value": "Debug" } ], not [ { "config": "Debug" } ]
```

so the section of my launch.json looks like this:

```
            }, "name": "(gdb) Launch current file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin",
            "environment": [
                {"name": "MSYSTEM", "value": "MINGW64"},
                {"name": "MSYSTEM_PREFIX", "value": "/mingw64"}
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
```

This "kind of" seems to work with the MingW and Ucrt compiler, but not with the Clang Compiler.
With Clang, the launch seems to be stuck  and doesn't strat to execute.
Is this setup correct at all?
Can I design my compiler selection in the planned way at all?
Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: [Multiple Launch Files in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277191/multiple-launch-files-in-visual-studio-code) ?   You have more experience in this subject, but is what is mentioned in this question/answer of help to you ?

Comment: You can have multiple entries under "configurations" in your launch.json.  Before starting the debug session, you can choose the config you would like to use.  It is described here: [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: when it is "not working" for "Clang Compiler", then you need to add the complete configuration you (try to) use for Clang.   (I do not have that installed), and maybe even add the tag: [tag:clang]

Comment: you could look at writing a buildsystem or a CMake config.